# Asymptotic solution to Airy Differential equation in two dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Does anyone know the asymptotic solution to the 2D Schrodinger equation with some known value of $\epsilon>0$ and $r_{0}=1$?

$$-\psi''(r)-\frac{1}{r}\psi'(r)+\ln\left|\frac{r}{r_{0}}\right |\psi(r)=\epsilon\psi(r)$$

The equation is presumably the two-dimensional analogue of the Airy differential equation in 1D.

The goal is to solve for the wave function of a system of non-relativistic charged particles interacting through a background Coulomb potential in 2 dimensions. The form of the Schrodinger equation presented above is valid for large values of $r$, i.e. $r\gg r_{0}$ and without loss of generality, the choice $r_{0}=1$ can be made. The 1D analogue of this problem would be the well-known Airy differential equation.

Comment: How is that, in any way, a 2D analogue of the Airy differential equation? If you're looking for generalizations, you should be looking at [the diffraction-catastrophe functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/36.2), of which the Airy function is the special case of 1D.

Comment: More detail on how you derived this equation might help.  Boundary values for the function also help.

Comment: The goal is to solve for the wave function of a system of non-relativistic charged particles interacting through a background Couloumb potential in 2 dimensions. The form of the Schrodinger equation presented above is valid for large values of r. The 1D analogue of this problem would lead to an Airy differential equation.

Comment: Please edit that into the question proper - expecting users to read all the comments to find this info is going to turn people off.  When you say "large $r$" large relative to what value ?